# Как в данной программе работает метод ageSwap?

Tags: java

Разбираю задачу и не понимаю каким образом Метод ageSwap поменял возраст девушек.
Прошу максимально популярно объяснить...

```
class ChkNum {

static class Student {
    String name;
    int age;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Student olga = new Student();
    olga.name = "Olga";
    olga.age = 21;

    Student vera = new Student();
    vera.name = "Veronika";
    vera.age = 15;

    System.out.println(olga.name + " is " + olga.age);
    System.out.println(vera.name + " is " + vera.age);

    ageSwap(olga, vera);

    System.out.println(olga.name + " is " + olga.age);
    System.out.println(vera.name + " is " + vera.age);

}
private static void ageSwap(Student a, Student b){
    int c = a.age;
    a.age = b.age;
    b.age = c;

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в методе `ageSwap()` вы в переменную `int c` кладёте возраст `a.age` - это возраст Ольги

```
int c = a.age;
```

Затем говорите, что возраст Ольги(`a.age`) равен возрасту Вероники (`b.age`).

```
a.age = b.age;
```

Затем говорите, что возраст Вероники(`b.age`) равен `c`.

```
b.age = c;
```

Comment: Спасибо, как возраст Ольги поменялся - понятно. А как поменялся возраст Вероники?

Comment: Все, понял. Спасибо)))